# How to put Email Alias name in SAS using EM_SENDER and EM_FROM directives?

Tags: email, sas

When using the below code with EM_* directives in EMAIL, I should get an alias name of "XYZ" in the outlook (I am using Outlook 2010) before the email address and also only the alias name in the inbox view. The email received in outlook doesn't have an alias.

```
Filename MAILBOX  email CT="text/html" ;
Data _null_ ;
  length HTML_DirLine $ 2048 ;

  fid = fopen('MAILBOX','O');

  /* write the TO email address */
  HTML_DirLine = '!EM_TO! ( "abc@abc.com" )' ;
  fputrc1  = fput(fid,trim(HTML_DirLine));
  rc = fwrite(fid);

  /* write the FROM email address */
  HTML_DirLine = '!EM_FROM! ( " XYZ  <abc@abc.com>" )' ;
  fputrc1  = fput(fid,trim(HTML_DirLine));
  rc = fwrite(fid);

  /* write the SENDER email address */
  HTML_DirLine = '!EM_SENDER! ( " XYZ <abc@abc.com>" )' ;
  fputrc1  = fput(fid,trim(HTML_DirLine));
  rc = fwrite(fid);

  /* write the Subject email address */
  HTML_DirLine = '!EM_SUBJECT! Test Email   ' ;
  fputrc1  = fput(fid,trim(HTML_DirLine));
  rc = fwrite(fid);

  /* write the Body of email message */
  HTML_DirLine = 'This is the test email. Pls ignore.' ;
  fputrc1  = fput(fid,trim(HTML_DirLine));
  rc = fwrite(fid);

  /* Send the email message */
  HTML_DirLine = '!EM_SEND!' ;
  fputrc1  = fput(fid,trim(HTML_DirLine));
  rc = fclose(fid);

 run ;
```

But when I use without directives it works fine. Below is the code,

```
Filename mailbox EMAIL ;
Data _null_ ;
File mailbox TO='abc@abc.com'
         Subject='Test Email message'
    from='XYZ <abc@abc.com>'
    sender='XYZ <abc@abc.com>' ;
put "Hi There,"
put "Please ignore this test email" ;
run ;
```

Any suggestions on how to make the alias name appear properly using directives in SAS? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the headers I get from your two test emails (as viewed in Mozilla Thunderbird):

Using directives:

```
Delivered-To: abc@gmail.com
Received: by 10.200.49.247 with SMTP id i52csp1678880qte;
        Tue, 26 Jul 2016 00:47:07 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.194.5.230 with SMTP id v6mr21227765wjv.92.1469519227576;
        Tue, 26 Jul 2016 00:47:07 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <abc@gmail.com>
Received: from localhost.localdomain (host217-39-41-194.range217-39.btcentralplus.com. [217.39.41.194])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dq8si18546922wjb.285.2016.07.26.00.47.06
        for <abc@gmail.com>;
        Tue, 26 Jul 2016 00:47:07 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning abc@gmail.com does not designate 217.39.41.194 as permitted sender) client-ip=217.39.41.194;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning abc@gmail.com does not designate 217.39.41.194 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=abc@gmail.com
Received: from localhost (localhost [IPv6:::1])
    by localhost.localdomain (Postfix) with SMTP id 38ACD226E8
    for <abc@gmail.com>; Tue, 26 Jul 2016 07:47:11 +0000 (UTC)
Date: 26 Jul 2016 07:47:11 -0000
Subject: =?utf-8?B?VGVzdCBFbWFpbA==?=
From: " XYZ  <abc@gmail.com>"@localhost.localdomain
Sender: ( " XYZ <abc@gmail.com>" )
To: abc@gmail.com
X-Mailer: 9.04.01M3P062415
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
        charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-Id: <20160726074711.38ACD226E8@localhost.localdomain>

VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgdGVzdCBlbWFpbC4gUGxzIGlnbm9yZS4=
```

Without directives:

```
Delivered-To: abc@gmail.com
Received: by 10.200.49.247 with SMTP id i52csp1677118qte;
        Tue, 26 Jul 2016 00:42:39 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.28.238.154 with SMTP id j26mr47226158wmi.94.1469518959773;
        Tue, 26 Jul 2016 00:42:39 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <abc@gmail.com>
Received: from localhost.localdomain (host217-39-41-194.range217-39.btcentralplus.com. [217.39.41.194])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id v2si18549245wjh.115.2016.07.26.00.42.39
        for <abc@gmail.com>;
        Tue, 26 Jul 2016 00:42:39 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning abc@gmail.com does not designate 217.39.41.194 as permitted sender) client-ip=217.39.41.194;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning abc@gmail.com does not designate 217.39.41.194 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=abc@gmail.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: from localhost (localhost [IPv6:::1])
    by localhost.localdomain (Postfix) with SMTP id 78EA7226F2
    for <abc@gmail.com>; Tue, 26 Jul 2016 07:42:44 +0000 (UTC)
Date: 26 Jul 2016 07:42:44 -0000
Subject: =?utf-8?B?VGVzdCBFbWFpbCBtZXNzYWdl?=
From: XYZ <abc@gmail.com>
Sender: XYZ <abc@gmail.com>
To: abc@gmail.com
X-Mailer: 9.04.01M3P062415
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
        charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-Id: <20160726074244.78EA7226F2@localhost.localdomain>

SGkgVGhlcmUsClBsZWFzZSBpZ25vcmUgdGhpcyB0ZXN0IGVtYWls
```

These both have a sender header, but when using the directives you seem to have picked up an extra set of brackets. I changed the appropriate line to:

```
HTML_DirLine = '!EM_SENDER! "XYZ <abc@abc.com>"' ;
```

and that seemed to fix it so that the same output is generated. You might still find that your email client does not display the sender even when the sender header is populated correctly if the server sending the emails is not listed on the MX records for the originating domain.

Incidentally, why are you using `fopen` / `fput` etc in the code with all the directives? `put` statements are simpler here and should work just as well.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The problem with my code was the spaces between parentheses. When I started backwards with your suggestion and added the parentheses, my code also worked.  
 `code`     HTML_DirLine = '!EM_FROM! ("XYZ  <abc@abc.com>")' ;
    HTML_DirLine = '!EM_SENDER! ("XYZ <abc@abc.com>")' ;`code`